# GetxController obs value inside other controller

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

I want to use LoginController token value inside userController to get the authToken which is an obs value but the value I am getting inside userController is non updated(i.e null which is initially set value).

**LoginController**

```
final token = "".obs;

isLoggedIn()async{

var storageToken = await _storage.read(key: "token");

token (storageToken);
print(token.value) //gives a value

}
```

**UserController**

```
var loginController = Get.put(LoginController());

home()async{

var token = loginController.token.value

print(token) // gives empty string

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because you initialized again your LoginController by putting this code `Get.put(LoginController())` on UserController.

You can approach this in two ways on your UserController:

```
var loginController = Get.find<LoginController>();
var token = loginController.token.value;
```

Or

```
var token = Get.find<LoginController>().token.value;
```